# Intercepting vue watch event before change happens

Tags: vue.js

Please let me know if it's possible to handle watch event, before the change actually happened. Can't google anything but can't believe this feature is missing.

TL;DR:

Basically, I need a button to be faded in/out using `<transition>` only when one particular prop (`liveModeEnabled`) changes. In all other cases transition shouldn't happen. The problem is that the watcher event is happening too late, when the change happened already and component re-rendered. For testing purposes, I tried putting my watcher's logic to `beforeUpdate` hook instead, and then all works well.

```html
<template>
  <transition :name="transitionEnabled ? 'button-fade' : null">
    <button v-if="shouldShowPlayButton">My button</button>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    liveModeEnabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    playoutSourceEnabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      transitionEnabled: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    liveModeEnabled () {
      this.transitionEnabled = true
      setTimeout(() => { this.transitionEnabled = false }, 300)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    shouldShowPlayButton() {
      return this.playoutSourceEnabled && this.liveModeEnabled
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the way it should work? This looks like XY problem. If a property should never have a value it was assigned with this means there should be 2 different properties, one of them could be a computed or be set explicitly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. All properties have and should have values, well except for transition name.

Comment: If you have a property Foo that affects the transition and you don't need to affect it at some moment this means that Foo shouldn't directly affect the transition. Instead it should conditionally affect Bar property, which affects the transition directly. I can't say what are Foo and Bar in your case because you have several properties, and the question isn't specific enough regarding how exactly this should work

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry, just noticed that I didn't make it clear which property exactly I'm expecting to be triggering the transition. I adjusted the description to make it more clear. So when `liveModeEnabled` changes to true or false, it should trigger the animation. But not when `playoutSourceEnabled` prop changed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that could understand your goal correctly, But if you want to have transition to your button component (that I called "myButton") **only** if the value of `liveModeEnabled` prop has been changed, maybe this code can do that for you:

> parent component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="my-3">
      <button v-on:click="show = !show">
        Toggle
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="my-3">
      <button v-on:click="funcTrans">
        Toggle-transition
      </button>
    </div>
    <myButton :liveModeEnabled = "show2" :playoutSourceEnabled = "show"></myButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myButton from '@/components/myButton.vue'
export default {
  name: "parentCompo",
  components: {
    myButton
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      show2: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    funcTrans: function () {
      this.show = !this.show;
      this.show2 = !this.show2;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> myButton component:

```html
<template>

    <transition :name="transitionEnabled ? 'button-fade' : null">
      <button v-if="shouldShowPlayButton">My button</button>
    </transition>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "myButton",
  props: {
    liveModeEnabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    playoutSourceEnabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      transitionEnabled: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    propArray: function (newArr, oldArr) {
      if (newArr[0] === oldArr[0]) {
        this.transitionEnabled = false;
      } else {
        this.transitionEnabled = true;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    shouldShowPlayButton() {
      return this.playoutSourceEnabled;
    },
    propArray() {
      return [this.liveModeEnabled, this.playoutSourceEnabled]
    }
  },

}
</script>

<style>
.button-fade-enter-active, .button-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
.button-fade-enter, .button-fade-leave-to  {
  opacity: 0;
}

</style>
```

With the code above I watched all props in an array. In this way if one of the props changes the Vue watch is called. After that we check that if the change is related to the **desired prop**, we set the `transitionEnabled` to **true**. But if the desired prop does not change, we set `transitionEnabled` to **false**.